# Append Names to Data in List

Tags: r, dataframe, list, lapply

```
set.seed(1)
d.A.100 = data.frame(x=runif(10), y = runif(10))
d.A.200 = data.frame(x=runif(10), y = runif(10))
d.B.100 = data.frame(x=runif(10), y = runif(10))
d.B.200 = data.frame(x=runif(10), y = runif(10))

mylist = list(d.A.100, d.A.200, d.B.100, d.B.200)
unlisted = do.call(rbind, mylist)
```

Let's say you make a list of dataframes like above and then you unlist them. I know I can just do a basic rbind but for later reasons this is how the data go. How can I add the name of the dataframe back into the unlisted dataframe so I have a new column 'dataname' equals to the name of the dataframe where those rows came from?

Comment: Your `mylist` doesn't have names, so you can't get them back reliably without changing how you construct `mylist` initially. A number of packages have functions for doing this quickly, and for adding the names/id column like *data.table*s `rbindlist` or *dplyr*s `bind_rows`.

Comment: Where do you want to get the names from? It would be simplest if you could name your list when you create it, then work with the list names. Otherwise, the names of the original objects  aren’t stored in / retrievable from the list, if that’s what your question is getting at.

Answer (score 2):

In base R. Instead of using `do.call` use `array2DF` in R >= 4.3. Note that You will need to have the names of the lists.

```
nms <- c('d.A.100', 'd.A.200', 'd.B.100', 'd.B.200')
d <- array2DF(array(mget(nms), length(nms), list(df_name = nms)))

data.frame(d, row.names = NULL) ## to discard the rownames
```

---

If you insist on using `do.call` or are stuck in older R versions,  use the following code:

```
nms <- c('d.A.100', 'd.A.200', 'd.B.100', 'd.B.200')
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, mylist, df_name=nms))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lst` function from the `tibble` package to create a named list, then use that name to create a new column.

Using this method, you don't need to manually create a vector of dataframe names.

```
library(tibble)

mylist <- lst(d.A.100, d.A.200, d.B.100, d.B.200)
do.call(rbind, lapply(names(mylist), \(i) transform(mylist[[i]], df_name = i)))

            x          y df_name
1  0.26550866 0.20597457 d.A.100
2  0.37212390 0.17655675 d.A.100
3  0.57285336 0.68702285 d.A.100
4  0.90820779 0.38410372 d.A.100
5  0.20168193 0.76984142 d.A.100
6  0.89838968 0.49769924 d.A.100
7  0.94467527 0.71761851 d.A.100
8  0.66079779 0.99190609 d.A.100
9  0.62911404 0.38003518 d.A.100
10 0.06178627 0.77744522 d.A.100
11 0.93470523 0.48208012 d.A.200
12 0.21214252 0.59956583 d.A.200
13 0.65167377 0.49354131 d.A.200
14 0.12555510 0.18621760 d.A.200
15 0.26722067 0.82737332 d.A.200
16 0.38611409 0.66846674 d.A.200
17 0.01339033 0.79423986 d.A.200
18 0.38238796 0.10794363 d.A.200
19 0.86969085 0.72371095 d.A.200
20 0.34034900 0.41127443 d.A.200
21 0.82094629 0.47761962 d.B.100
22 0.64706019 0.86120948 d.B.100
23 0.78293276 0.43809711 d.B.100
24 0.55303631 0.24479728 d.B.100
25 0.52971958 0.07067905 d.B.100
26 0.78935623 0.09946616 d.B.100
27 0.02333120 0.31627171 d.B.100
28 0.47723007 0.51863426 d.B.100
29 0.73231374 0.66200508 d.B.100
30 0.69273156 0.40683019 d.B.100
31 0.91287592 0.33907294 d.B.200
32 0.29360337 0.83944035 d.B.200
33 0.45906573 0.34668349 d.B.200
34 0.33239467 0.33377493 d.B.200
35 0.65087047 0.47635125 d.B.200
36 0.25801678 0.89219834 d.B.200
37 0.47854525 0.86433947 d.B.200
38 0.76631067 0.38998954 d.B.200
39 0.08424691 0.77732070 d.B.200
40 0.87532133 0.96061800 d.B.200
```